# is the iphone MkMapView multithreaded?

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios4, mkmapview

Is MKMapView multithreaded?  That is, can I receive events while my main thread is processing something?

Answer (score 0):

MKMapView is internally multithreaded, meaning it will send tasks like downloading new map tiles to another thread.

I question why a main thread is "processing something"? User interaction event processing, including events involved in manipulating a `MKMapView` are usually processed on the main thread in iOS apps. Any work that may block the processing of user interaction events should be sent to additional threads. The work may be a heavy calculation, or it may just be a blocking call to download network data. The other threads should return the data to the main thread to update the interface such as the `MKMapView`.